# Python3 -- objectpath ...broken?

Tags: python, python-3.x, objectpath

After hours of unsuccessfully trying to use objectpath in a Python3-script, I made the following simple experiment:

```
>>> from objectpath import *
>>> tree=Tree({"a":1})
>>> tree.execute("$.a")
```

Expected output: 1

Success with python (2)

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from objectpath import *
>>> tree=Tree({"a":1})
>>> tree.execute("$.a")
1
>>>
```

Error with python3:

Is there something wrong with my installation of Python3 ?
objectpath in P3 neither works in scripts nor on console

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from objectpath import *
>>> tree=Tree({"a":1})
>>> tree.execute("$.a")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 398, in tokenize_python
 yield type_map[t[0]], t[1]
KeyError: 4

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/interpreter.py", line 605, in execute
tree=self.compile(expr)
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/interpreter.py", line 38, in compile
ret=EXPR_CACHE[expr]=parse(expr,self.D)
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 464, in parse
r=expression().getTree()
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 449, in expression
left=t.led(left)
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 264, in led
advance()
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 161, in advance
token=nextToken()
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 413, in tokenize
for ID, value in source:
File "/home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/objectpath/core/parser.py", line 405, in tokenize_python
raise SyntaxError("Syntax error")
```

Answer (score 1):

To run this in Python 3.x you should `pip3 install objectpath` otherwise it won't work.

See below how I ran your code:

```
dell@dell-XPS-15-9572:~/Desktop$ pip3 install objectpath
Collecting objectpath
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/6a/ed435be72edd1d60b7363cbb38c34aff3004fee02d1c7f9f01435c318cdb/objectpath-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: objectpath
Successfully installed objectpath-0.5
dell@dell-XPS-15-9572:~/Desktop$ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> from objectpath import *
>>> tree=Tree({"a":1})
>>> tree.execute("$.a")
1
>>>
```

Comment: But mine says : Collecting objectpath
 Using cached  - HOW could I enforce pip3 to download the correct - seems it uses the P2-version from cache

Comment: Try `pip uninstall objectpath` to uninstall the package.

Comment: you would have a version 2 of pip and a version 3. you can use python3 -mpip or python2 -mpip but i have always used pip in a virtual env.